# How can I avoid changing WordPress gmt offset manually each time daylight savings time is changed?

Tags: wordpress

**Background**

Our company sells a web application based out of Sweden. We run WordPress 3.5.1. Our API servers are in Sweden. But some of our customers are scattered in different countries. Each customer has it's own WordPress site in our wordpress multisite installation. So our time formatting is strictly in need of a correct `gmt_offset` option handling in Wordpress.

During summertime, Swedens timezone is GMT+2

During wintertime, Swedens timezone is GMT+1.

Of course, these values are different for different customers in different countries. The problem is that the timezone **changes twice per year** because of daylight savings time and this needs to be configured in Wordpress manually

**Problem**

This means, two times per year we have to change the `gmt_offset` options manually for ALL customers, which is frustrating and in my mind unnecessary. I haven't found any information how this can be automated.

Any ideas how to solve this problem? Can WordPress automatically change the `gmt_offset` option, depending on a site's country location?

Answer (score 6):

To have WordPress automatically reflect daylight saving time, **select a city, not offset hours** in WP-admin > Settings > General > Timezone. You will then see a notification like this:

> This timezone is currently in daylight saving time.
>
> Standard time begins on: Sunday 25.10. 04:00.