# Converting a Time from a database to BST with PHP

Tags: php, datetime, datetime-format

So I've trying all sorts of combinations to get a date from my database (using Wordpress) to display in British Summer Time and I cannot get anything to work.

Is there any simple solution that can take the date string and make sure that in Summer Time in the UK it's an hour on from UTC time?

```
$classJson = $class->info;
$classJsonAsArray = json_decode($classJson, TRUE);

$classStartDate = strtotime($class->periodStart);
$classStartTime = date('H:i',$classStartDate);
```

So currently $class->periodStart returns: 2022-04-06 08:30:00

The time of that event should be 9.30am

All I need it to do is display the correct time, as at the moment, on the front end it displays as 8.30am.

Comment: [How can I avoid changing WordPress gmt offset manually each time daylight savings time is changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26278594/how-can-i-avoid-changing-wordpress-gmt-offset-manually-each-time-daylight-saving) ?

Comment: Yeah, that isn't the issue here. I already have those set correctly. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DateTime` handles timezones quite well.

```php
$dateStringInUtc = '2022-04-06 08:30:00';
$date = new DateTime($dateStringInUtc, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));

echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // will output 2022-04-06 09:30:00
```

Comment: Perfect, bit of tweaking to that has fixed it. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Working with DateTime and timezones like in the accepted answer is the better way.

But it also works with strtotime if the timezone is appended to the date string. Date then returns the local time for a timestamp.

```
$utcDate = '2022-04-06 08:30:00';
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($utcDate.' UTC'));
```